# Is there a sliding drawer widget provided by google?

Tags: android

The YouTube app for android has a sliding drawer. Is this a widget provided by the SDK? There seem to be a bunch of opensource ones, but they all behave in different ways. Is there an 'official' one provided by google?

[image]

There is a SlidingDrawer widget class, but it's deprecated (and I didn't understand the deprecation message):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google does offer a DrawerView via a widget that is fairly easy to implement in an app. Here is the [Google library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for it. This is how I implemented the DrawerView in this [Sample Code](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Hacking_Environment). The [CheeseSquare example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) by Google also implements the DrawerView nicely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not official. Google doesn't release it.

Here you can find a good library.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu